# Sticky cumsum/cumprod numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Foreword: I'll probably update the title as I suspect I only lack the correct wording for my problem. (Which makes it a potential duplicate, sorry about that). I'd appreciate suggestions to do so.

Here's functionally what I want to accomplish:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
b = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])

# What I want:
result = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
# [1, 0] -> 1 
# [0, 1] -> 0
# [0, 0] -> the last value
```

To try and be clearer, here's a naive implementation (Goal being obviously to do that with numpy methods):

```py
def sticky_cumsum(a, b):
    result = []
    for val_a, val_b in zip(a, b):
        if val_a:
            results.append(1)
        elif val_b: # assuming both can't be true
            results.append(0)
        else: # assuming first iteration won't be [0, 0]
            results.append(results[-1])
    return results
```

**Edit 1:** As pointed out in the comments, [0, 0] in first position has an undefined behaviour. 
That was a simplified case of my actual context (which would be irrelevant).
It's assumed that [0, 0] will never happen in first position.

Comment: What should happen if `a = np.array([0])` and `b = np.array([0])`?

Comment: Similar to what Daweo said, you have an undefined situation when your `a, b` arrays both start with `0`. Unless you can guarantee that will never happen.

Comment: That was a simplified case of my actual context which would be irrelevant.
It's assumed that [0, 0] will never happen in first position.
Sorry, I should have made that clearer

Comment: Are you able to use Cython? I can post a solution for your interest if you like? It may be quicker than numpy for large arrays

Comment: I am, I would love that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `np.select` to mask `(1,0)` and `(0,1)`. Then use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60638280/sticky-cumsum-cumprod-numpy) to fill in the `nan` with previous values:

```
arr = np.select((a==1, b==1), (1,0), np.nan)

# inspired by the linked question
mask = np.isnan(arr)
idx = np.where(~mask,np.arange(len(mask)), 0)
np.maximum.accumulate(idx,out=idx)
out = arr[idx]
```

Output:

```
array([1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.])
```

Comment: Totally amazing, exactly fits my need.

Answer (score 0):

## An alternative using Cython

If you are able to use Cython, you could use something like the following, which can be run from a Jupyter Notebook using the following

```
%load_ext Cython
```

Then in a seperate cell, run.

```
%%cython -a

from cython cimport boundscheck, wraparound
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np

@boundscheck(False)
@wraparound(False)
def cython_sticky_cumsum(int[::1] a, int[::1] b):

    cdef size_t i, N = a.size
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int32_t, ndim=1] result = np.empty(N, dtype=np.int32)

    for i in range(N):
        if a[i] == 1:
            result[i] = 1
        elif b[i] == :
            result[i] = 0
        else:
            result[i] = result[i-1]

    return result
```

If you're concerned with performance/using large arrays, something like the above may be preferable. I guess this depends on what you find more readable.

```
a = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
b = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])

cython_sticky_cumsum(a, b)
# array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1])
```

## Crude test

For much larger arrays, such as,

```
a = np.tile(np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]), 1000000)
b = np.tile(np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]), 1000000)
```

and running the tests,

```
%timeit cython_sticky_cumsum(a,b)
%timeit sticky_cumsum(a, b)
```

outputs

```
28.4 ms ± 1.86 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
2.5 s ± 97.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```